# Secure an Angular JS app with Spring Security

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I have created a Spring Boot app and I have my front-end app in the `/resources/static` folder.

For the routing, I am using Angular JS UI Router library.
I have defined a route, which I only want to be accessed by the admin and now I am trying to secure it using Spring Security.

Here is my WebSecurity Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  {

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER").and()
            .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
}

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
      httpSecurity
      .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/#/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
      .and()
      .formLogin()
      .and()
      .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/member", "/member/**").permitAll()
      .antMatchers(
              HttpMethod.GET,
              "/",
              "/*.html",
              "/favicon.ico",
              "/**/*.html",
              "/**/*.css",
              "/**/*.js",
              "/**/**/*.css",
              "/**/**/*.js",
              "/**/**/*.html",
              "/**/**/**/*.css",
              "/**/**/**/*.js",
              "/**/**/**/*.html",
              "/**/**/**/**/*.css",
              "/**/**/**/**/*.js"          
      ).permitAll()
      .antMatchers("/auth/**",  "/member/**", "/account/**").permitAll() 

      .and()
      .csrf().disable();

  }
 }
```

The route I am trying to secure can be accessed through http://localhost:8080/#/admin.
 However, whenever I am accessing that route, no login is requested and the page can be viewed by anyone.
Is it there another approach I should follow?

Answer (score 1):

The URL: `http://localhost:8080/#/admin` is mapped to `/` in your `permitAll` list instead of the `/#/admin` rule, since `#/admin` part is just URL fragment, and usually not the business of the server side.

You have to define an **API** between your frontend and backend. Usually in RESTful  web services form, and serve at `/api/*` path. Secure the path, and let your frontend talk to your backend through those APIs only.

Answer (score 0):

It is eaiser to fix your issue,

Update

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/#/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
```

To

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/#/admin").hasRole("ADMIN").anyRequest().authenticated()
```

For every matchers, you always need with `permitAll()` or `authenticated()` for it.

Comment: This worked, but now I should log in to have access to all the end-points even though they were available before